# BOOL declaration

Tags: objective-c

I have an `if` statement which compares two `NSString`. If the two strings are equal, I assign the 'YES' value to a `BOOL` called `myBool` that I use later in a `UITableViewCell`.

It's my first `BOOL` implementation ever and I'm not sure that it's the best way to do it despite it working correctly.

```
// in view controller .m
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL myBool; 

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

     if ([score1 isEqualToString:score2])
      {     

      [self setmyBool:YES]; 
      [self reloadTableView]; 
      }
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

 if (_myBool) {
// display same score string if the strings are equal
  cell.scoreLabel.text = @"Same score";
}
return cell;
}
```

What do you think? Is it a proper implementation? I'm not sure that it must be a `property` and `nonatomic, assign`. I would appreciate any tips or guidance which can help me to improve my code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using a *property* for the boolean attribute is fine. Properties have many
advantages: they encapsulate an objects value (i.e. the actual implementation
is hidden from the outside, it need not be an instance variable), they are
public (instance variables are by default not visible from other classes),
they can be *observed* (via Key-Value Observing). In the ancient times of Manual Reference Counting they made the memory management easier.

In the case of a "simple" attribute that is *only* used within the implementation
the difference is small and (in my opinion) a matter of taste. But if you use
a property then you should use the property accessor methods
consequently.

> `@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL myBool;`

"nonatomic" is fine. For historical reasons, "atomic" is the default, but you
seldom need that. "assign" is the only choice for properties which are not
Objective-C objects and you can omit it. "myBool" is a badly chosen name because
it gives no hint about its meaning. I would recommend something like

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL equalScores;
```

---

> `[self setmyBool:YES];`

There is actually a typo here, it should be

```
[self setMyBool:YES];
```

but the dot notation is more concise and makes it clear that you set
a property (using the suggested name):

```
self.equalScores = YES;
```

---

> `if (_myBool) { ... }`

Here you access the underlying instance variable directly and not via
its accessor method. It should be

```
if (self.equalScores) { ... }
```

(The only exception are `init` and `dealloc` methods where the instance
variable is accessed directly because the object is not fully initialized.)

Comment: The dot notation is more readable and looks better for me. I'm using it a lot for other properties so it's amazing that I can use it for BOOL's too. Martin, thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: Another time you need to directly access a property's underlying instance variable would be in its overridden getter or setter (to avoid infinite recursion).

Answer (score 8):

I want to address a couple issues the other answers do not address.

First, if we're going to override a view controller life cycle method such as `viewWillAppear:`, we mustn't forget to call `super`:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // my code
}
```

Next, we can do some other neat things with Objective-C properties.

For example, rather than explicitly setting `equalScores` at any point, why don't we just have its value calculated on the fly when necessary?  It seems unlikely, but what would happen, under your current set up, if you were to change score1 or score2 after setting `equalScores`, but before building the table view cell?  You'd have inaccurate data.

Instead, I suggest we make `equalScores` a `readonly` property:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) BOOL equalScores;
```

And now let's override the default implementation of the getter:

```
- (BOOL)equalScores {
    return [score1 isEqualToString:score2];
}
```

Now we've simplified our code, made `equalScores` more accurate more of the time, and made it easier to avoid repeating ourselves in the future.

We can refactor your existing code as such:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (self.equalScores) { // equivalent to: if ([score1 isEqualToString:score2])
        [self reloadTableView];
    }
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if (self.equalScores) {
        // display same score string if the strings are equal
        cell.scoreLabel.text = @"Same score";
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed answer! Possibly could you tell me that what can go wrong if I don't use the `[super viewWillAppear:animated];`? Because I didn't use it in the past and don't experienced any issues. (Maybe I was just lucky)

Comment: Probably nothing in this specific case, but out of OOP principle, you generally should be calling to `super` when you're overriding a superclass's method.  Failing to call `super` in other cases will result in "bugs" that are hard to diagnose.  For example, failing to call `super` in `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: Great. So it's better (recommended) to use it then not use it in the most cases. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. You should only omit it intentionally and when you know what and why you are doing it.

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to Code Review! Most of what I am covering is minor, but I think it needs to be said.

I am assuming this a typo, because properties cannot be declared in the implementation file unless declared inside a category:

```
// in view controller .m
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL myBool;
```

Your indentation, spacing and braces are very inconsistent.  You are using two different brace styles:

```
 if ([score1 isEqualToString:score2])
  {    

 if (_myBool) {
```

It is fine to use either one of these styles, but you should make sure to use the same style throughout your code.

You are not tabbing properly and you have strange stray single spaces:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

 if (_myBool) {
// display same score string if the strings are equal
  cell.scoreLabel.text = @"Same score";
}
return cell;
}
```

I think this looks a lot cleaner:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if (_myBool) {
        // display same score string if the strings are equal
        cell.scoreLabel.text = @"Same score";
    }

    return cell;
}
```

This line is probably too long the way that you have it, and can be shortened by doing this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

Xcode will automatically line up the colons for you if you put a line break after each argument in a method declaration.

This comment is an indication that there is a design problem with the code:

```
// display same score string if the strings are equal
```

It should not be necessary to explain the purpose of the line of code that follows this comment.  To me this indicates that the code should be moved somewhere else where it would not need explanation.  It is probably bad design to have this happening when creating the `UITableViewCell`. However, I do not have a better suggestion for how to organize the code at this time.

Comment: Thank you for the useful advices, you are right. I need to make some changes.